# What's the statistics of questions on Meta?

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics

Is there a statistics on how many questions are duplicates, closed and active\open (not closed or duplicate) questions on Meta?

Comment: You'll have to define "real" here

Comment: @random: Please see edit

Comment: I'm sure there's [data](http://data.stackexchange.com) on that.

Comment: @Jack: How do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for ["close reason"](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/queries?q=close%20reason) you will find [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/17934/distribution-of-close-reasons) being one of the most popular.

Here's a breakdown:

```
Exact duplicate              | 8186
Too localized                |  789
Subjective and argumentative |  420
Off topic                    | 2328
```

Comment: Thanks Jack. I guess, I can then calculate the rest of the statistics